# Adding language management to joomla modules

Tags: joomla

This [article](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Adding_language_management) is about adding language management to Joomla components. I tried this for modules but that tutorial does not work for modules.  How can I add language management to modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the installation zip file of your module include a `language` folder containing the language files you want, named like this:
`bg-BG.mod_mymodule.ini` , `de-DE.mod_mymodule.ini` etc.

Then in the installation `mod_mymodule.xml` include a language section like this:

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="bg-BG">bg-BG.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
    <language tag="de-DE">de-DE.mod_mymodule.ini</language>
</languages>
```

To use the above, in the code of your module you echo `JText` like this:

`JText::_('MYMODULE_MY_STRING_HERE')` where `MYMODULE_MY_STRINGHERE` is defined in the language `.ini` files for each language like this:

`MYMODULE_MY_STRINGHERE="What you want it to say"`